# Preventing overlap of text in D3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, pie-chart, overlap

I've been googling around, but I can't seem to grasp this.

My situation is that the countries overlap when presented on the pie chart:

This is an example of what is happening:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqnqz/3/)

[image]

I am a total beginner to `D3` and am trying to prevent text overlap. Is there like a text margin attribute that I can add such that my labels don't overlap each other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**: See the answer to [D3 put arc labels in a Pie Chart if there is enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792552/d3-put-arc-labels-in-a-pie-chart-if-there-is-enough-space/19801529#19801529) for a more comprehensive solution.

---

I do not know any generic method of laying text elements such that they do not overlap.

However, there is a workaround for your problem by rotating the labels and scaling the graph such that they do not overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/2uT7F/

```js
// Get the angle on the arc and then rotate by -90 degrees
var getAngle = function (d) {
    return (180 / Math.PI * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 - 90);
};

g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + pos.centroid(d) + ") " +
                    "rotate(" + getAngle(d) + ")"; }) 
    .attr("dy", 5) 
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; });
```

Answer (score 3):

One more solution would be to change the order of the data with the USA being first. You might find the angle of the pie layout to be more readable.

```
var data_values = [48, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4];
var titles = ["USA","Pakistan", "Israel", "Netherlands", "Italy", "Uruguay",       "United Kingdom", "Austria", "China"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rocky1616/oLzsrd4o/

Musically_ut's solution would work nicely here as well. You can even take the angle down a bit if that worked in your design.

```
  var getAngle = function (d) {
      return (180 / Math.PI * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 + 45);
  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2uT7F/26/

You would need to create a if else block to take care of the USA item but this is a start if it helps.