# Donut Pie Chart labels overlapping

Tags: d3.js, charts, donut-chart

This is my problem: [image]

I'm having trouble so that these labels do no overlap, i tried to move the start and endangle but with no success, it just makes the lines overlap the chart.
I've searched for a solution but it does not apply to my specific case.
Has anyone solved a similar problem?

My Code:

```
//pie
var svg = d3.select("article")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");

var width = document.getElementById('cartao2').offsetWidth,
    height = document.getElementById('cartao2').offsetHeight / 1.2,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value +1;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4)
    //THESE ARE THE LINES TO CHANGE STARTING POINT
    /*.startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle + Math.PI+4; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle + Math.PI+4; });*/

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)
     //THESE ARE THE LINES TO CHANGE STARTING POINT
     /*.startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle + Math.PI+4; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle + Math.PI+4; });*/

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

//CARREGAR DADOS
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()  
    .domain(["20" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358","20" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358","20" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "30" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "40" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "70" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "70" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "70" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358", "70" + "h" + " " + "PRJ-358"])
    .range(["#36ADB5", "#00CBED", "#006C73", "#00A1AB", "#0094BA", "#006D99", "#1C5A5E", "#006C73", "#00A1AB"]);


function randomData (){
    var labels = color.domain();
    return labels.map(function(label){
        return { label: label, value: Math.random()}
    });
}

/*d3.json("data.json", function(json) {
    change(json);//pass teh loaded the json to change function for drawing.
});*/


//DADOS PARA  TESTE
change(randomData());

/*d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function(){
        change(randomData());
    });*/

function change(data) {

    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
        .attr("class", "slice");

    slice       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    slice.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("font-size", "17px")
        .attr("color", "#6f6f6f")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.label;
        });



    function midAngle(d){
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 3;
    }

    text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline")
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); });


    polyline.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };          
        });

    polyline.exit()
        .remove();
};
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681724/how-to-avoid-labels-overlapping-in-a-d3-js-pie-chart and https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/

Comment: Those solutions did not worked in this graphic unfortunately.

Comment: @Nunocruz did you solve it? can you share your solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and i gave this to some developers and they didn't solve it either, i had to change library, we used Syncfusion.

Comment: Also you can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008292/d3-js-pie-charts-labels-overlapping/55378977#55378977 as a solution for d3 v4

Answer (score 0):

This will be definitely too late for you, but maybe anyone else coming here is searching for a solution.

When calculating the position of each label, we have to check whether we already calculated a label in a predefined range around the new Y coordinate (pos[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPjsc.png) in your case). In my case, I used for the "predefined range" the height of the label with some padding. I called this `minLabelYDiff`

applied to your code, the solution looks something like this:

```js
    ///Determines how much a label at least must be away from other labels
    const minLabelYDiff = 20;
    let usedYLabelCoordinates = [];

...
    text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                 
                //check if there is already another label which y coordinate is too close.
                //note: a lesser y component means the label moves up
                for (const existingY of usedYLabelCoordinates) {
                  if (Math.abs(pos[1] - existingY) < minLabelYDiff) {
                    if (pos[1] <= existingY) {
                      // note: a lesser Y means the label moves up
                      pos[1] = existingY - minLabelYDiff;
                    } else {
                      pos[1] = existingY + minLabelYDiff;
                    }
                  }
                }

                usedYLabelCoordinates.push(pos[1]);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
...
```

The changing of the connector lines isn't that trivial because we not only need to set the y coordinate to the correct position but also calculate the correct place on the outerArc of the x coordinate.
Luckily, this can be done using the pythagorean theorem (calculate y out of x and the radius)

I don't know how my solution can directly integrate into your example, but you can derive that from my code regarding adding the poylines

```js
    let arcOuterRadius = radius * 0.75;
    let arc = d3
      .arc<d3.PieArcDatum<Datum>>()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.4) // This is the size of the donut hole
      .outerRadius(arcOuterRadius);

    // Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
    let outerArc = d3
      .arc<d3.PieArcDatum<Datum>>()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.8)
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

    //To get the correct possition of the connector lines
    let connectorLineStartArc = d3
      .arc<d3.PieArcDatum<Datum>>()
      .innerRadius(arcOuterRadius + 5)
      .outerRadius(arcOuterRadius + 5);
...
 let usedCYConnectorCorordinates: number[] = [];
    // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
    svg
      .selectAll("allPolylines")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("polyline")
      .attr("class", "donut-connector")
      .attr("points", (d): any => {
        if (d.data.quantity === 0) {
          return;
        }
        // The position right above the arc (created an additional arc for that)
        let posA = connectorLineStartArc.centroid(d); // line insertion in the slice
        //The position from posA to the center of the outerArc (same x coordinate as the label)
        let posB = outerArc.centroid(d); // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
        // y is same as posB but x gets longer to the label
        let posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
        let midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2; // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
        posC[0] = radius * 0.9 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left

        //check if there is already another label which y coordinate is too close.
        //note: a lesser y component means the label moves up
        for (const existingY of usedCYConnectorCorordinates) {
          if (Math.abs(posC[1] - existingY) < minLabelYDiff) {
            if (posC[1] <= existingY) {
              // note: a lesser Y means the label moves up
              posC[1] = existingY - minLabelYDiff;
            } else {
              posC[1] = existingY + minLabelYDiff;
            }

            //Because posC changed, we need to recalculate posB using the pythagoreon theorem
            posB[1] = posC[1];
            posB[0] = Math.sqrt(
              Math.pow(
                (outerArc.outerRadius()(d) - outerArc.innerRadius()(d)) / 2 +
                  outerArc.innerRadius()(d),
                2
              ) - Math.pow(posB[1], 2)
            );
          }
        }

        usedCYConnectorCorordinates.push(posC[1]);
        return [posA, posB, posC];
      });
...
```

It then looks like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPjsc.png)