# D3.js 'Pie Charts Labels' Overlapping

Tags: d3.js

Hi StackOverflow community. I tried to find the solution for a problem I'm having and was unable to get anything helpful. The closest thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072332/donut-pie-chart-labels-overlapping) which seems to not have a solution. I'm a complete beginner to D3.js so this may also be why I'm having trouble resolving the situation. I tried digging through the documentation as well with no success. So here's my problem. I was trying to do some data visualization stuff and stumbled upon [this](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) pie chart in the D3.js example library, which I thought was pretty nifty. Once I started putting a large amount of values into the graph though I noticed I had problems with overlapping labels as can be seen below. I've only altered the code from the example page to make it so I can create multiple charts. Besides that it's essentially the same. Thanks for any help or information anyone can provide!

[Overlapping Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPnp.png)

Comment: this should help you https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid labels overlapping in a D3.js pie chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681724/how-to-avoid-labels-overlapping-in-a-d3-js-pie-chart)

Answer (score 3):

This will work only for d3 v4. The idea is to compare each node with the rest and move its position if collision is detected. The following code snippet uses `this.texts` as d3 selection of the labels. Once a collision is detected the element will be moved below - might not be optimised for a specific case.

```
const nodes = this.texts.nodes();
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
      const previous = nodes[i];
      const elem = nodes[j];
      const thisbb = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        prevbb = previous.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (!(thisbb.right < prevbb.left ||
        thisbb.left > prevbb.right ||
        thisbb.bottom < prevbb.top ||
        thisbb.top > prevbb.bottom)) {
        const matrix = previous.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
        d3.select(elem).attr('transform', `translate(${matrix.e}, ${matrix.f + prevbb.bottom - prevbb.top})`);

      }
      const elemMatrix = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
      pieData[j].pos = [elemMatrix.e, elemMatrix.f];
    }
  }
```